# Issue with calculation VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I create a program thast when someone insert 3 values in three textboxes and presses the button, it shows the result the code is this:

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim d As Integer
    Dim p As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim v As Integer

    d = TextBox1.Text
    p = TextBox2.Text
    y = TextBox3.Text
    v = Label5
    v = d * (1 + (p / 100)) ^ y


End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

End Sub
End Class
```

The problem is that when I press the button, nothing happens. If you could help my with the code it would be nice

Thank you in advance

Comment: Turn on Option Strict. That would have found this error for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the entries to numeric values ​​before doing the math operations and need to assign the result to the 'text' property of the label5 and not to the control.

Something like this:

```
Dim d As Integer = Integer.Parse(TextBox1.Text)
Dim p As Integer = Integer.Parse(TextBox2.Text)
Dim y As Integer = Integer.Parse(TextBox3.Text)
Dim v As Integer = d * (1 + (p / 100)) ^ y

Label5.Text = v.ToString()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but the problem is that when i press the button the result of the calculation is not the same as the result of the same calculation in a calculator. Why is that happen?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not assigning your result to anything that will preserve the value once it exits your method. I am assuming that `Label5` is where you want your answer to be. You also are dividing by 100 with integers and putting the result into an integer also, Integers will only give you whole numbers no fractions, I would suggest using a `Double` instead. Also you should use [`Option Strict On`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) on the top of your class, (from link) this *"restricts implicit data type conversions to only widening conversions, disallows late binding, and disallows implicit typing that results in an Object type"*, it will help keep subtle bugs from working their way into your code.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim d As Integer
    Dim p As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim v As Double

    If Not Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, d) Then
        ShowError(TextBox1.Name)
    End If
    If Not Integer.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, p) Then
        ShowError(TextBox2.Name)
    End If
    If Not Integer.TryParse(TextBox3.Text, y) Then
        ShowError(TextBox3.Name)
    End If

    v = d * (1 + (p / 100)) ^ y
    Label5.Text = v.ToString()

End Sub

Sub ShowError(control As String)
    MsgBox(control & " Input Error", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation Or MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Input Error")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but the problem is that when i press the button the result of the calculation is not the same as the result of the same calculation in a calculator. Why is that happen?

Comment: How are they different?  Did you use a double as I suggested ?